# Weasyprint GLib error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf-generation, glib

I installed WeasyPrint and all packages that were listed in the Weasyprint - documentation

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2 
and Python 2.7
And installed Weasyprint in my virtualenv .

Now when i try : 
HTML('http://weasyprint.org/').write_pdf('/tmp/weasyprint-website.pdf')

I get following message in my console :

```
pydev debugger: starting
Ignored border-radius: 6px at 12:3, unknown property.
Ignored background: linear-gradient(#000, #111) at 59:3, invalid value.
Ignored box-shadow: 0 0 1em #888 at 65:3, unknown property.
Ignored text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #444 at 77:3, unknown property.
Ignored transition: color 0.25s at 150:3, unknown property.
Ignored box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ddd at 167:3, unknown property.
Ignored border-radius: 0.2em at 168:3, unknown property.
Ignored text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #111 at 171:3, unknown property.
Ignored transition: background 0.7s ease at 251:3, unknown property.
Ignored border-radius: 0.2em at 279:3, unknown property.
Ignored box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b7b7b7 at 280:3, unknown property.
Ignored background: url(img/content_haut.png) no-repeat top left,
url(img/bas.png) no-repeat bottom right at 301:3, invalid value.
Ignored border-radius: 0.2em at 305:3, unknown property.
Ignored transition: background-color 0.3s linear at 368:3, unknown property.
Ignored box-shadow: 0 0 5px #D60 at 373:3, unknown property.
Parse error at 7:1, unknown at-rule in stylesheet context: @font-face
Parse error at 12:1, unknown at-rule in stylesheet context: @font-face
Parse error at 17:1, unknown at-rule in stylesheet context: @font-face
Parse error at 22:1, unknown at-rule in stylesheet context: @font-face
Parse error at 26:1, unknown at-rule in stylesheet context: @font-face
Parse error at 31:1, unknown at-rule in stylesheet context: @font-face

(process:49474): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:49474): GLib-CRITICAL **: void g_once_init_leave(volatile void *, gsize): assertion `result != 0' failed

(process:49474): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:49474): GLib-CRITICAL **: void g_once_init_leave(volatile void *, gsize): assertion `result != 0' failed

(process:49474): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:49474): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()
```

I googled the GLib-GObject-CRITICAL but didn't find a solution, does anyone knows how to fix this?
I'm relatively new to Python so if you need more info let me know !

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in WeasyPrint. Please keep the discussion on the issue tracker: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/41